# Autocomplete Textbox fetching suggestions from database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have created 2 autosuggest textboxes in which one is fetching data from server-side and another is fetching data from client-side.But server-side textbox is not working.Can anyone point out the error in my code.

Following is my HTML Code:

```
<html>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css" /> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="languages.js"></script> 
  <body>
    <label for="languagesClientInput">Select Language(client-side): </label>
    <input id="languagesClientInput" />
    <br />
    <label for="languagesServerInput">Select Language (server-side): </label>
    <input id="languagesServerInput" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Following is Js Code:

```
$(function() {
    var languages = [
         "C",
  "C++",
  "Core Java",
  "Advance Java",
  "PHP",
  ".NET",
  "XML",
  "HTML",
  "Javascript",
  "jQuery",
  "JSON",
  "Ajax",
  "C#",
  "ABC ALGOL",
  "ADA",
  "ABLE",
  "COBOL",
  "BLUE",
  "Pearl",
  "Python",
  "Oracle",
  "Haskell",
  "BASIC",
  "BeanShell",
  "Bliss",
  "BETA",
  "GOTRAN",
  "FORTRAN",
  "Focal",
  "Genie",
  "GOAL",
  "GROOVY",
  "JOSS",
  "JEAN",
  "JOVIAL",
  "JOY",
  "Maple",
  "MATLAB",
  "MORTAN",
  "MUMPS",
  "Miranda",
  "NetRexx",
  "NPL",
  "NXT-G"
    ];

$("#languagesClientInput").autocomplete( { source: languages });
$("#languagesServerInput").autocomplete( { source: "languages.php" });

});
```

Following is Php Code:

```
<?php

$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

$languages = array(
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Core Java",
  "Advance Java",
  "PHP",
  ".NET",
  "XML",
  "HTML",
  "Javascript",
  "jQuery",
  "JSON",
  "Ajax",
  "C#",
  "ABC ALGOL",
  "ADA",
  "ABLE",
  "COBOL",
  "BLUE",
  "Pearl",
  "Python",
  "Oracle",
  "Haskell",
  "BASIC",
  "BeanShell",
  "Bliss",
  "BETA",
  "GOTRAN",
  "FORTRAN",
  "Focal",
  "Genie",
  "GOAL",
  "GROOVY",
  "JOSS",
  "JEAN",
  "JOVIAL",
  "JOY",
  "Maple",
  "MATLAB",
  "MORTAN",
  "MUMPS",
  "Miranda",
  "NetRexx",
  "NPL",
  "NXT-G"
);

function filter($language) {
  global $searchTerm;
  return stripos($language, $searchTerm) !== false;
}

print(json_encode(array_values(array_filter($languages, "filter"))));

?>
```

Comment: check this [http://codepad.org/6FG8Tzr1](http://codepad.org/6FG8Tzr1) Found no error...

Comment: Right...But y I am not getting the required output?

Answer (score 0):

The `array_filter` function fails. If you remove it you will get the data you need.
I actually think you have made a mistake there by writing `array_filter` instead of just `filter` to call the function you wrote above.

Comment: you have an error there. Just remove "filter" function to see that it works and work a bit on your function, because it doesn't filter.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the array_values function. This worked for me:

```
// languages.php
<?php

function filter($language) {

    global $searchTerm;

    return stripos( $language, $searchTerm ) !== false;

}


$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

$languages = array(
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Core Java",
    "Advance Java",
    "PHP",
    ".NET",
    "XML",
    "HTML",
    "Javascript",
    "jQuery",
    "JSON",
    "Ajax",
    "C#",
    "ABC ALGOL",
    "ADA",
    "ABLE",
    "COBOL",
    "BLUE",
    "Pearl",
    "Python",
    "Oracle",
    "Haskell",
    "BASIC",
    "BeanShell",
    "Bliss",
    "BETA",
    "GOTRAN",
    "FORTRAN",
    "Focal",
    "Genie",
    "GOAL",
    "GROOVY",
    "JOSS",
    "JEAN",
    "JOVIAL",
    "JOY",
    "Maple",
    "MATLAB",
    "MORTAN",
    "MUMPS",
    "Miranda",
    "NetRexx",
    "NPL",
    "NXT-G"
);

$jsonData = array_filter( $languages, "filter" );

print( json_encode( $jsonData ) );



?>
```

Comment: I am still not getting required output.Is there any browser problem?

Comment: What output are you expecting? Are you getting any output at all?

Comment: I am getting output in the client-side textbox.But not getting any output in server-side textbox....

Comment: I've edited my post to show the full languages.php file. Seems to be working fine. Have you made sure the source property in the autocomplete method is pointing to the correct file? Check in firebug or some other browser development tool to see if the serve is actually responding to anything.

Comment: Do I need to add the "languages.php" file in the html code.It is included in the .js file?

Comment: You should have all the php code above in a separate file called languages.php and it should be in the same directory as the javascript file or put it where you like, just make sure the path in the source property is changed so that it points to that file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58635/discussion-between-matt-herbstritt-and-newbie).

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in MySQL database;

```
CREATE TABLE `tag` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

INSERT INTO `tag` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'php'),
(2, 'php frameword'),
(3, 'php tutorial'),
(4, 'jquery'),
(5, 'ajax'),
(6, 'mysql'),
(7, 'wordpress'),
(8, 'wordpress theme'),
(9, 'xml');
```

**index.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Auto Complete Input box</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#tag").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
        selectFirst: true
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <label>Tag:</label>
    <input name="tag" type="text" id="tag" size="20"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**autocomplete.php**

```
<?php
    $q=$_GET['q'];
    $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
    $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','autofield') or die("Database Error");
    $sql="SELECT name FROM tag WHERE name LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY name";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    if($result)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo $row['name']."\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

**jquery.autocomplete.css**

```
.ac_results {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.ac_results ul {
    width: 100%;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.ac_results li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
    /* 
    if width will be 100% horizontal scrollbar will apear 
    when scroll mode will be used
    */
    /*width: 100%;*/
    font: menu;
    font-size: 12px;
    /* 
    it is very important, if line-height not setted or setted 
    in relative units scroll will be broken in firefox
    */
    line-height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.ac_loading {
    background: white url('indicator.gif') right center no-repeat;
}

.ac_odd {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.ac_over {
    background-color: #0A246A;
    color: white;
}
```

**jquery.autocomplete.js**

```
/*
 * jQuery Autocomplete plugin 1.1
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Jörn Zaefferer
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * Revision: $Id: jquery.autocomplete.js 15 2009-08-22 10:30:27Z joern.zaefferer $
 */

;(function($) {

$.fn.extend({
    autocomplete: function(urlOrData, options) {
        var isUrl = typeof urlOrData == "string";
        options = $.extend({}, $.Autocompleter.defaults, {
            url: isUrl ? urlOrData : null,
            data: isUrl ? null : urlOrData,
            delay: isUrl ? $.Autocompleter.defaults.delay : 10,
            max: options && !options.scroll ? 10 : 150
        }, options);

        // if highlight is set to false, replace it with a do-nothing function
        options.highlight = options.highlight || function(value) { return value; };

        // if the formatMatch option is not specified, then use formatItem for backwards compatibility
        options.formatMatch = options.formatMatch || options.formatItem;

        return this.each(function() {
            new $.Autocompleter(this, options);
        });
    },
    result: function(handler) {
        return this.bind("result", handler);
    },
    search: function(handler) {
        return this.trigger("search", [handler]);
    },
    flushCache: function() {
        return this.trigger("flushCache");
    },
    setOptions: function(options){
        return this.trigger("setOptions", [options]);
    },
    unautocomplete: function() {
        return this.trigger("unautocomplete");
    }
});

$.Autocompleter = function(input, options) {

    var KEY = {
        UP: 38,
        DOWN: 40,
        DEL: 46,
        TAB: 9,
        RETURN: 13,
        ESC: 27,
        COMMA: 188,
        PAGEUP: 33,
        PAGEDOWN: 34,
        BACKSPACE: 8
    };

    // Create $ object for input element
    var $input = $(input).attr("autocomplete", "off").addClass(options.inputClass);

    var timeout;
    var previousValue = "";
    var cache = $.Autocompleter.Cache(options);
    var hasFocus = 0;
    var lastKeyPressCode;
    var config = {
        mouseDownOnSelect: false
    };
    var select = $.Autocompleter.Select(options, input, selectCurrent, config);

    var blockSubmit;

    // prevent form submit in opera when selecting with return key
    $.browser.opera && $(input.form).bind("submit.autocomplete", function() {
        if (blockSubmit) {
            blockSubmit = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    // only opera doesn't trigger keydown multiple times while pressed, others don't work with keypress at all
    $input.bind(($.browser.opera ? "keypress" : "keydown") + ".autocomplete", function(event) {
        // a keypress means the input has focus
        // avoids issue where input had focus before the autocomplete was applied
        hasFocus = 1;
        // track last key pressed
        lastKeyPressCode = event.keyCode;
        switch(event.keyCode) {

            case KEY.UP:
                event.preventDefault();
                if ( select.visible() ) {
                    select.prev();
                } else {
                    onChange(0, true);
                }
                break;

            case KEY.DOWN:
                event.preventDefault();
                if ( select.visible() ) {
                    select.next();
                } else {
                    onChange(0, true);
                }
                break;

            case KEY.PAGEUP:
                event.preventDefault();
                if ( select.visible() ) {
                    select.pageUp();
                } else {
                    onChange(0, true);
                }
                break;

            case KEY.PAGEDOWN:
                event.preventDefault();
                if ( select.visible() ) {
                    select.pageDown();
                } else {
                    onChange(0, true);
                }
                break;

            // matches also semicolon
            case options.multiple && $.trim(options.multipleSeparator) == "," && KEY.COMMA:
            case KEY.TAB:
            case KEY.RETURN:
                if( selectCurrent() ) {
                    // stop default to prevent a form submit, Opera needs special handling
                    event.preventDefault();
                    blockSubmit = true;
                    return false;
                }
                break;

            case KEY.ESC:
                select.hide();
                break;

            default:
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = setTimeout(onChange, options.delay);
                break;
        }
    }).focus(function(){
        // track whether the field has focus, we shouldn't process any
        // results if the field no longer has focus
        hasFocus++;
    }).blur(function() {
        hasFocus = 0;
        if (!config.mouseDownOnSelect) {
            hideResults();
        }
    }).click(function() {
        // show select when clicking in a focused field
        if ( hasFocus++ > 1 && !select.visible() ) {
            onChange(0, true);
        }
    }).bind("search", function() {
        // TODO why not just specifying both arguments?
        var fn = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : null;
        function findValueCallback(q, data) {
            var result;
            if( data && data.length ) {
                for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if( data[i].result.toLowerCase() == q.toLowerCase() ) {
                        result = data[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if( typeof fn == "function" ) fn(result);
            else $input.trigger("result", result && [result.data, result.value]);
        }
        $.each(trimWords($input.val()), function(i, value) {
            request(value, findValueCallback, findValueCallback);
        });
    }).bind("flushCache", function() {
        cache.flush();
    }).bind("setOptions", function() {
        $.extend(options, arguments[1]);
        // if we've updated the data, repopulate
        if ( "data" in arguments[1] )
            cache.populate();
    }).bind("unautocomplete", function() {
        select.unbind();
        $input.unbind();
        $(input.form).unbind(".autocomplete");
    });


    function selectCurrent() {
        var selected = select.selected();
        if( !selected )
            return false;

        var v = selected.result;
        previousValue = v;

        if ( options.multiple ) {
            var words = trimWords($input.val());
            if ( words.length > 1 ) {
                var seperator = options.multipleSeparator.length;
                var cursorAt = $(input).selection().start;
                var wordAt, progress = 0;
                $.each(words, function(i, word) {
                    progress += word.length;
                    if (cursorAt <= progress) {
                        wordAt = i;
                        return false;
                    }
                    progress += seperator;
                });
                words[wordAt] = v;
                // TODO this should set the cursor to the right position, but it gets overriden somewhere
                //$.Autocompleter.Selection(input, progress + seperator, progress + seperator);
                v = words.join( options.multipleSeparator );
            }
            v += options.multipleSeparator;
        }

        $input.val(v);
        hideResultsNow();
        $input.trigger("result", [selected.data, selected.value]);
        return true;
    }

    function onChange(crap, skipPrevCheck) {
        if( lastKeyPressCode == KEY.DEL ) {
            select.hide();
            return;
        }

        var currentValue = $input.val();

        if ( !skipPrevCheck && currentValue == previousValue )
            return;

        previousValue = currentValue;

        currentValue = lastWord(currentValue);
        if ( currentValue.length >= options.minChars) {
            $input.addClass(options.loadingClass);
            if (!options.matchCase)
                currentValue = currentValue.toLowerCase();
            request(currentValue, receiveData, hideResultsNow);
        } else {
            stopLoading();
            select.hide();
        }
    };

    function trimWords(value) {
        if (!value)
            return [""];
        if (!options.multiple)
            return [$.trim(value)];
        return $.map(value.split(options.multipleSeparator), function(word) {
            return $.trim(value).length ? $.trim(word) : null;
        });
    }

    function lastWord(value) {
        if ( !options.multiple )
            return value;
        var words = trimWords(value);
        if (words.length == 1) 
            return words[0];
        var cursorAt = $(input).selection().start;
        if (cursorAt == value.length) {
            words = trimWords(value)
        } else {
            words = trimWords(value.replace(value.substring(cursorAt), ""));
        }
        return words[words.length - 1];
    }

    // fills in the input box w/the first match (assumed to be the best match)
    // q: the term entered
    // sValue: the first matching result
    function autoFill(q, sValue){
        // autofill in the complete box w/the first match as long as the user hasn't entered in more data
        // if the last user key pressed was backspace, don't autofill
        if( options.autoFill && (lastWord($input.val()).toLowerCase() == q.toLowerCase()) && lastKeyPressCode != KEY.BACKSPACE ) {
            // fill in the value (keep the case the user has typed)
            $input.val($input.val() + sValue.substring(lastWord(previousValue).length));
            // select the portion of the value not typed by the user (so the next character will erase)
            $(input).selection(previousValue.length, previousValue.length + sValue.length);
        }
    };

    function hideResults() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(hideResultsNow, 200);
    };

    function hideResultsNow() {
        var wasVisible = select.visible();
        select.hide();
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        stopLoading();
        if (options.mustMatch) {
            // call search and run callback
            $input.search(
                function (result){
                    // if no value found, clear the input box
                    if( !result ) {
                        if (options.multiple) {
                            var words = trimWords($input.val()).slice(0, -1);
                            $input.val( words.join(options.multipleSeparator) + (words.length ? options.multipleSeparator : "") );
                        }
                        else {
                            $input.val( "" );
                            $input.trigger("result", null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    };

    function receiveData(q, data) {
        if ( data && data.length && hasFocus ) {
            stopLoading();
            select.display(data, q);
            autoFill(q, data[0].value);
            select.show();
        } else {
            hideResultsNow();
        }
    };

    function request(term, success, failure) {
        if (!options.matchCase)
            term = term.toLowerCase();
        var data = cache.load(term);
        // recieve the cached data
        if (data && data.length) {
            success(term, data);
        // if an AJAX url has been supplied, try loading the data now
        } else if( (typeof options.url == "string") && (options.url.length > 0) ){

            var extraParams = {
                timestamp: +new Date()
            };
            $.each(options.extraParams, function(key, param) {
                extraParams[key] = typeof param == "function" ? param() : param;
            });

            $.ajax({
                // try to leverage ajaxQueue plugin to abort previous requests
                mode: "abort",
                // limit abortion to this input
                port: "autocomplete" + input.name,
                dataType: options.dataType,
                url: options.url,
                data: $.extend({
                    q: lastWord(term),
                    limit: options.max
                }, extraParams),
                success: function(data) {
                    var parsed = options.parse && options.parse(data) || parse(data);
                    cache.add(term, parsed);
                    success(term, parsed);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // if we have a failure, we need to empty the list -- this prevents the the [TAB] key from selecting the last successful match
            select.emptyList();
            failure(term);
        }
    };

    function parse(data) {
        var parsed = [];
        var rows = data.split("\n");
        for (var i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var row = $.trim(rows[i]);
            if (row) {
                row = row.split("|");
                parsed[parsed.length] = {
                    data: row,
                    value: row[0],
                    result: options.formatResult && options.formatResult(row, row[0]) || row[0]
                };
            }
        }
        return parsed;
    };

    function stopLoading() {
        $input.removeClass(options.loadingClass);
    };

};

$.Autocompleter.defaults = {
    inputClass: "ac_input",
    resultsClass: "ac_results",
    loadingClass: "ac_loading",
    minChars: 1,
    delay: 400,
    matchCase: false,
    matchSubset: true,
    matchContains: false,
    cacheLength: 10,
    max: 100,
    mustMatch: false,
    extraParams: {},
    selectFirst: true,
    formatItem: function(row) { return row[0]; },
    formatMatch: null,
    autoFill: false,
    width: 0,
    multiple: false,
    multipleSeparator: ", ",
    highlight: function(value, term) {
        return value.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + term.replace(/([\^\$\(\)\[\]\{\}\*\.\+\?\|\\])/gi, "\\$1") + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>");
    },
    scroll: true,
    scrollHeight: 180
};

$.Autocompleter.Cache = function(options) {

    var data = {};
    var length = 0;

    function matchSubset(s, sub) {
        if (!options.matchCase) 
            s = s.toLowerCase();
        var i = s.indexOf(sub);
        if (options.matchContains == "word"){
            i = s.toLowerCase().search("\\b" + sub.toLowerCase());
        }
        if (i == -1) return false;
        return i == 0 || options.matchContains;
    };

    function add(q, value) {
        if (length > options.cacheLength){
            flush();
        }
        if (!data[q]){ 
            length++;
        }
        data[q] = value;
    }

    function populate(){
        if( !options.data ) return false;
        // track the matches
        var stMatchSets = {},
            nullData = 0;

        // no url was specified, we need to adjust the cache length to make sure it fits the local data store
        if( !options.url ) options.cacheLength = 1;

        // track all options for minChars = 0
        stMatchSets[""] = [];

        // loop through the array and create a lookup structure
        for ( var i = 0, ol = options.data.length; i < ol; i++ ) {
            var rawValue = options.data[i];
            // if rawValue is a string, make an array otherwise just reference the array
            rawValue = (typeof rawValue == "string") ? [rawValue] : rawValue;

            var value = options.formatMatch(rawValue, i+1, options.data.length);
            if ( value === false )
                continue;

            var firstChar = value.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
            // if no lookup array for this character exists, look it up now
            if( !stMatchSets[firstChar] ) 
                stMatchSets[firstChar] = [];

            // if the match is a string
            var row = {
                value: value,
                data: rawValue,
                result: options.formatResult && options.formatResult(rawValue) || value
            };

            // push the current match into the set list
            stMatchSets[firstChar].push(row);

            // keep track of minChars zero items
            if ( nullData++ < options.max ) {
                stMatchSets[""].push(row);
            }
        };

        // add the data items to the cache
        $.each(stMatchSets, function(i, value) {
            // increase the cache size
            options.cacheLength++;
            // add to the cache
            add(i, value);
        });
    }

    // populate any existing data
    setTimeout(populate, 25);

    function flush(){
        data = {};
        length = 0;
    }

    return {
        flush: flush,
        add: add,
        populate: populate,
        load: function(q) {
            if (!options.cacheLength || !length)
                return null;
            /* 
             * if dealing w/local data and matchContains than we must make sure
             * to loop through all the data collections looking for matches
             */
            if( !options.url && options.matchContains ){
                // track all matches
                var csub = [];
                // loop through all the data grids for matches
                for( var k in data ){
                    // don't search through the stMatchSets[""] (minChars: 0) cache
                    // this prevents duplicates
                    if( k.length > 0 ){
                        var c = data[k];
                        $.each(c, function(i, x) {
                            // if we've got a match, add it to the array
                            if (matchSubset(x.value, q)) {
                                csub.push(x);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }               
                return csub;
            } else 
            // if the exact item exists, use it
            if (data[q]){
                return data[q];
            } else
            if (options.matchSubset) {
                for (var i = q.length - 1; i >= options.minChars; i--) {
                    var c = data[q.substr(0, i)];
                    if (c) {
                        var csub = [];
                        $.each(c, function(i, x) {
                            if (matchSubset(x.value, q)) {
                                csub[csub.length] = x;
                            }
                        });
                        return csub;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
};

$.Autocompleter.Select = function (options, input, select, config) {
    var CLASSES = {
        ACTIVE: "ac_over"
    };

    var listItems,
        active = -1,
        data,
        term = "",
        needsInit = true,
        element,
        list;

    // Create results
    function init() {
        if (!needsInit)
            return;
        element = $("<div/>")
        .hide()
        .addClass(options.resultsClass)
        .css("position", "absolute")
        .appendTo(document.body);

        list = $("<ul/>").appendTo(element).mouseover( function(event) {
            if(target(event).nodeName && target(event).nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'LI') {
                active = $("li", list).removeClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE).index(target(event));
                $(target(event)).addClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);            
            }
        }).click(function(event) {
            $(target(event)).addClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
            select();
            // TODO provide option to avoid setting focus again after selection? useful for cleanup-on-focus
            input.focus();
            return false;
        }).mousedown(function() {
            config.mouseDownOnSelect = true;
        }).mouseup(function() {
            config.mouseDownOnSelect = false;
        });

        if( options.width > 0 )
            element.css("width", options.width);

        needsInit = false;
    } 

    function target(event) {
        var element = event.target;
        while(element && element.tagName != "LI")
            element = element.parentNode;
        // more fun with IE, sometimes event.target is empty, just ignore it then
        if(!element)
            return [];
        return element;
    }

    function moveSelect(step) {
        listItems.slice(active, active + 1).removeClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
        movePosition(step);
        var activeItem = listItems.slice(active, active + 1).addClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
        if(options.scroll) {
            var offset = 0;
            listItems.slice(0, active).each(function() {
                offset += this.offsetHeight;
            });
            if((offset + activeItem[0].offsetHeight - list.scrollTop()) > list[0].clientHeight) {
                list.scrollTop(offset + activeItem[0].offsetHeight - list.innerHeight());
            } else if(offset < list.scrollTop()) {
                list.scrollTop(offset);
            }
        }
    };

    function movePosition(step) {
        active += step;
        if (active < 0) {
            active = listItems.size() - 1;
        } else if (active >= listItems.size()) {
            active = 0;
        }
    }

    function limitNumberOfItems(available) {
        return options.max && options.max < available
            ? options.max
            : available;
    }

    function fillList() {
        list.empty();
        var max = limitNumberOfItems(data.length);
        for (var i=0; i < max; i++) {
            if (!data[i])
                continue;
            var formatted = options.formatItem(data[i].data, i+1, max, data[i].value, term);
            if ( formatted === false )
                continue;
            var li = $("<li/>").html( options.highlight(formatted, term) ).addClass(i%2 == 0 ? "ac_even" : "ac_odd").appendTo(list)[0];
            $.data(li, "ac_data", data[i]);
        }
        listItems = list.find("li");
        if ( options.selectFirst ) {
            listItems.slice(0, 1).addClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
            active = 0;
        }
        // apply bgiframe if available
        if ( $.fn.bgiframe )
            list.bgiframe();
    }

    return {
        display: function(d, q) {
            init();
            data = d;
            term = q;
            fillList();
        },
        next: function() {
            moveSelect(1);
        },
        prev: function() {
            moveSelect(-1);
        },
        pageUp: function() {
            if (active != 0 && active - 8 < 0) {
                moveSelect( -active );
            } else {
                moveSelect(-8);
            }
        },
        pageDown: function() {
            if (active != listItems.size() - 1 && active + 8 > listItems.size()) {
                moveSelect( listItems.size() - 1 - active );
            } else {
                moveSelect(8);
            }
        },
        hide: function() {
            element && element.hide();
            listItems && listItems.removeClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
            active = -1;
        },
        visible : function() {
            return element && element.is(":visible");
        },
        current: function() {
            return this.visible() && (listItems.filter("." + CLASSES.ACTIVE)[0] || options.selectFirst && listItems[0]);
        },
        show: function() {
            var offset = $(input).offset();
            element.css({
                width: typeof options.width == "string" || options.width > 0 ? options.width : $(input).width(),
                top: offset.top + input.offsetHeight,
                left: offset.left
            }).show();
            if(options.scroll) {
                list.scrollTop(0);
                list.css({
                    maxHeight: options.scrollHeight,
                    overflow: 'auto'
                });

                if($.browser.msie && typeof document.body.style.maxHeight === "undefined") {
                    var listHeight = 0;
                    listItems.each(function() {
                        listHeight += this.offsetHeight;
                    });
                    var scrollbarsVisible = listHeight > options.scrollHeight;
                    list.css('height', scrollbarsVisible ? options.scrollHeight : listHeight );
                    if (!scrollbarsVisible) {
                        // IE doesn't recalculate width when scrollbar disappears
                        listItems.width( list.width() - parseInt(listItems.css("padding-left")) - parseInt(listItems.css("padding-right")) );
                    }
                }

            }
        },
        selected: function() {
            var selected = listItems && listItems.filter("." + CLASSES.ACTIVE).removeClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
            return selected && selected.length && $.data(selected[0], "ac_data");
        },
        emptyList: function (){
            list && list.empty();
        },
        unbind: function() {
            element && element.remove();
        }
    };
};

$.fn.selection = function(start, end) {
    if (start !== undefined) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if( this.createTextRange ){
                var selRange = this.createTextRange();
                if (end === undefined || start == end) {
                    selRange.move("character", start);
                    selRange.select();
                } else {
                    selRange.collapse(true);
                    selRange.moveStart("character", start);
                    selRange.moveEnd("character", end);
                    selRange.select();
                }
            } else if( this.setSelectionRange ){
                this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
            } else if( this.selectionStart ){
                this.selectionStart = start;
                this.selectionEnd = end;
            }
        });
    }
    var field = this[0];
    if ( field.createTextRange ) {
        var range = document.selection.createRange(),
            orig = field.value,
            teststring = "<->",
            textLength = range.text.length;
        range.text = teststring;
        var caretAt = field.value.indexOf(teststring);
        field.value = orig;
        this.selection(caretAt, caretAt + textLength);
        return {
            start: caretAt,
            end: caretAt + textLength
        }
    } else if( field.selectionStart !== undefined ){
        return {
            start: field.selectionStart,
            end: field.selectionEnd
        }
    }
};

})(jQuery);
```

Download jquery.min.js and rename it to jquery.js

Now open index.php in your localhost/server and test it. Follow the similar method with your wordlist.